# Get list of DataFrame column names for non-float columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a list of column names from a DataFrame corresponding to columns that aren't of type float. Right now I have

```
categorical = (df.dtypes.values != np.dtype('float64'))
```

which gives me a boolean array of whether column names are not float or not, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. Specifically, I would like a list of column names that correspond to the 'True' values in my boolean array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `df.columns`:

```
categorical = df.columns[(df.dtypes.values != np.dtype('float64'))]
```

Or get [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) of columns selected by [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
categorical = df.columns.difference(df.select_dtypes('float64').columns)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7.,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5.,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B    C    D  E  F
0  a  4  7.0  1.0  5  a
1  b  5  8.0  3.0  3  a
2  c  4  9.0  5.0  6  a
3  d  5  4.0  7.0  9  b
4  e  5  2.0  1.0  2  b
5  f  4  3.0  0.0  4  b

categorical = df.columns.difference(df.select_dtypes('float64').columns)
print (categorical)
Index(['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'], dtype='object')
```